# All functions available in SOQL

Tags: soql

I read the [soql documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) on developer.salesforce.com, there was no page listing all functions available in SOQL

So I extracted the following functions available in SOQL

Aggregate functions :

- `count`
- `count_distinct`
- `avg`
- `min`
- `max`
- `sum`

Date functions :

- `calendar_month`
- `calendar_quarter`
- `calendar_year`
- `day_in_month`
- `day_in_week`
- `fiscal_month`
- `fiscal_quarter`
- `fiscal_year`
- `hour_in_day`
- `week_in_month`
- `week_in_year`
- `day_only`
- `convertTimeZone`

Format function :

- `format`

To label function :

- `toLabel`

Currency function :

- `convertCurrency`

Is there any undocumented function or a function I forgot in my list ?

Comment: Date literals ? Is that your question?

Comment: @RahulSharma Thanks Date literals I know about them,  yeah I am just looking to list all functions available in SOQL...

Comment: Just an error of inattention: missing the `min` function.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your purposes, you might want to also include formula fields since there are a lot of [SQL function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm) equivalents that aren't part of SOQL itself, but can be defined in a formula field.

For example, the `UPPER()` function in SQL:

```
SELECT UPPER(lowercase) AS uppercase FROM table;
```

in Salesforce would be a formula field named `Uppercase__c`, with a formula `UPPER(Lowercase__c)`, that could be queried by:

```
SELECT Uppercase__c FROM CustomObject__c
```